# Any limits imposed on AWS Redshift JDBC similar to limits imposed on Redshift Data API

Tags: amazon-redshift

AWS Redshift docs have very detailed info about limits imposed on Redshift Data API, for ex: `Transactions per second (TPS) for the ExecuteStatement API = 30` or `The maximum query result size is 100 MB (after gzip compression)` , `The maximum duration of a query is 24 hours` .

See more at

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html

Question:

Are there any similar limits imposed on interaction via AWS Redshift JDBC driver?
Can't find such level of details, any reference, link you can point me to? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no such restrictions on using a JDBC connection to a Redshift cluster.  I've seen queries running for weeks and people trying to load TBs of result data and wondering why their laptop disk fills up. However, the RS Data API restrictions are generally reasonable and pushing past these for a JDBC connection should be done with understanding of what performing these actions can do to the Redshift cluster.

For example all result data is routed through the leader node where final ordering is performed.  If massive return data is happening then the leader node can be working hard on this and not compiling other queries.  Its network connection will be saturated with this large return set and not be as responsive to others' connections.

This said your cluster has some setup WLM and parameter group settings that can limit things like query run time.  Just by moving to a JDBC connection doesn't mean that no rules are in play.